# Send print from windows 7 to printer at windows XP changes the format of the spool file

Tags: windows-7, printing, windows-xp, .emf, spooler

I have this weird problem

I have a printer installed at windows XP and I configured the print processor like this
"winprint---> NT EMF 1.003"

So the .spl file is an EMF Format file.

Now i share this printer to my office lan.

When I send a print from another windows XP pc there is no problem.

When I send from a windows 7 pc, the .spl file is in pcl3 format. 
why?

I try to install this printer to windows 7 pc with two methods.

a) Add Printer--> A network printer or a printer attached to another computer.
In this case when i print, a .spl file is created only in windows XP machine, in pcl3 format.

b) Add Printer--> Local printer attached to the computer. I create then a new Local Port, that is the network path to the shared printer.
In this case when I print a .spl file is created in windows 7, that is EMF format!!!!!!, and another one in windows XP, that is pcl3 format.

Why is this happening? I want when i print from windows 7 to the share printer, to create an emf format .spl file in windows XP.

Comment: From Vista and above windows started using "client side rendering" (CSR). This means that where possible windows would render the document on the client rather than the server, and send the completed job to the server. I believe this may be what you are experiencing. From memory there is a registry key that you can flick to disable CSR.

Comment: Thanks. The solution was to go to local group policy--> computer configuration --> printers and change the value of "Always print job on sernver" to Enabled